# My iOS images appear opaque when I run the app

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I'm using full screen images in my app, and when I see them on XCode they look just fine, but when i run it on the simulator, iPad mini or iPhone 6 they look completely opaque. Why could this be?

Comment: Without any further information, context, etc, we can't help. For example, how transparent are they? Are they all in the same view controller? Are they behind / in front of any other views? Screenshots and code can help us answer.

Comment: We need some more info from you. Do images have transparent background? How do you add them to the screen? What properties are changed? Maybe couple of pictures would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the opaque property on your UIImageView (assuming that's what you're using)

Additionally, as a debugging aid, I'd re-export the images using standard settings